# Using getchar() to take multiple values.

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Could I somehow use getchar() to run through a command line until I hit a '\n'. 
Say I want to scan in all the values I enter such as.

21 23 1 78 54 '\n'. I want to scan all the five values into an array. I am unable to scan them in. Is it because of the spacing between each value? Or is there a function we could use to do it ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Dont know much about c but cant you use a loop to break those values by space or something similar?

Comment: Why not to use scanf?

Comment: Try this: `while((input=getchar()) != '\n')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not bent on using `getchar()` then I have a straightforward solution using `scanf` with the `%d` conversion specifier:

```
while (i < ARRAY_SIZE && scanf("%d", &a[i]) == 1)
    i++ ;
```

The `%d` conversion specifier tells `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace and read up to the next non-digit character. The return value is the number of successful conversions and assignments. Since we're reading a single integer value, the return value should be 1 on success.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef int Type;

typedef struct vector {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    Type *array;
} Vector;

Vector *vec_make(void){
    Vector *v = malloc(sizeof(*v));
    if(v){
        v->size = 0;
        v->capacity=16;
        v->array = malloc(v->capacity * sizeof(Type));
    }
    return v;
}

void vec_free(Vector *v){
    free(v->array);
    free(v);
}

void vec_add(Vector *v, Type value){
    v->array[v->size++] = value;
    if(v->size == v->capacity){
        Type *temp;
        temp = realloc(v->array, sizeof(Type)*(v->capacity += 16));
        if(!temp){
            perror("realloc at vec_add");
            vec_free(v);
            exit(-1);
        }
        v->array = temp;
    }
}

int main(void){
    size_t size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", INT_MIN);
    char buffer[size+1];
    int ch, i = 0;
    Vector *v = vec_make();

    while(1){
        ch=getchar();
        if(isspace(ch)){
            if(i == 0){
                if(ch == '\n')
                    break;
                continue;
            }
            buffer[i] = 0;
            //buffer validate as int => omitted
            vec_add(v, atoi(buffer));
            if(ch == '\n')
                break;
            i = 0;
        } else {
            if(ch == EOF)
                break;
            buffer[i++] = ch;
            if(i == size){
                fprintf(stderr, "error : too long\n");
                //skip upto delimiter?
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //print
    for(i = 0; i < v->size; ++i){
        if(i)
            putchar(',');
        printf("%d", v->array[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    vec_free(v);
    return 0;
}
```