# Reading Multiple lines(different lengths) from file in c

Tags: c, arrays, file, file-io

I want to load following contents of a file into an array.
file contents:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[2,3]
[2]
[1,4,5,6,8,9]
```

Now, I want to load first line into integer array `'a' ( a ={1,2,3,4,5})` and do some operation. free a. take next line and load into `'a' (a = {2,3})` and do some operation and so on.. till end of file.

Note: Each line can have different count of numbers.(we don't know the count of numbers in each line)

How to scan each line and take only numbers and store them in an array?
my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define DELIM " \r\n\t!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|\\:\"'?¿/.,<>’¡º×÷‘"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int lineIdx = 0;
    int charIdx = 0;
    int TERMINATOR = 1753775;
    char *token = "tmp";
    char *orLine = malloc(4096 * sizeof(char));
    char **importedLine = malloc(4096 * sizeof(orLine));
    int tokenizedArray[100][100];// = malloc(sizeof(orLine * numOfLines));

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    while(fscanf(f, "%s", orLine) != EOF){
        importedLine[lineIdx] = orLine;
        for(charIdx = 0; charIdx < strlen(importedLine[lineIdx]); charIdx++){
            importedLine[lineIdx][charIdx] = importedLine[(lineIdx)][(charIdx+1)];
        }
        importedLine[lineIdx][(strlen(importedLine[lineIdx])-1)] = NULL;
        token = strtok(importedLine[lineIdx], ", ");
        charIdx = 0;
        while(token != NULL){
            tokenizedArray[lineIdx][charIdx] = atoi(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ", ");
            charIdx++;
        }
        tokenizedArray[lineIdx][(charIdx)] = TERMINATOR;
        lineIdx++;
    }
    tokenizedArray[(lineIdx)][0] = TERMINATOR;
    fclose(f);
    lineIdx = 0;
    charIdx = 0;
    while(tokenizedArray[lineIdx][charIdx] != TERMINATOR){
        while(tokenizedArray[lineIdx][charIdx] != TERMINATOR){
            printf("%d ",tokenizedArray[lineIdx][charIdx]);
            charIdx++;
        }
        lineIdx++;
        charIdx = 0;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Code will eventually become mandatory to solve this. Show yours, and maybe we can tell you what you're doing wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: @LakshmanKollipara Kindly add your code so that we can help you improve it .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31233360/971127

Comment: Here is the link to my code. [link] (http://dpaste.com/3XKB80E)
and Input file. [link] (http://dpaste.com/0V2J3MA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int Type;

typedef struct vector {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    Type *array;
} Vector;

Vector *vec_make(void){
    Vector *v = malloc(sizeof(*v));
    if(v){
        v->size = 0;
        v->capacity=16;
        v->array = malloc(v->capacity * sizeof(Type));
    }
    return v;
}

void vec_free(Vector *v){
    free(v->array);
    free(v);
}

void vec_add(Vector *v, Type value){
    v->array[v->size++] = value;
    if(v->size == v->capacity){
        Type *temp;
        temp = realloc(v->array, sizeof(Type)*(v->capacity += 16));
        if(!temp){
            perror("realloc at vec_add");
            vec_free(v);
            exit(-1);
        }
        v->array = temp;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(f == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char line[4096];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, f)){
        static const char *delimiter = "[,] \t\n";
        Vector *v = vec_make();

        char *number = strtok(line, delimiter);//Format don't check
        for(; number; number = strtok(NULL, delimiter)){
            vec_add(v, atoi(number));
        }
        //some operation : print out
        int size = v->size;
        int *a = v->array;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            if(i)
                putchar(',');
            printf("%d", a[i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
        vec_free(v);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Read a complete line
2. Check that your syntax is correct: line must start with `[` and end with `]`
3. Remove these square brackets
4. split line at `,`. Now you know the number of elements
5. Allocate an array of this length
6. parse all sub-fields into integers

Comment: Thanks @DrKoch .
Can you elaborate more on this.
I am a non CS guy and started working on C and files recently.

Comment: Well, try for yourself first, show your efforts. Everybody will be happy to help you then.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly

1 First open file in reading mode `FILE*p;p=fopen("file.txt","r");`

2 Take any char array say

`char acline[40];int i;`

3 Now using loop read content of file line by line and store them into acline

`while (!feof(p)) {for(i=0;i<40;i++)acline[i]=NULL;fgets(acline,40,p);// your code , whole line is in your array , insert if condition to check []}`

4 Close file `fclose(p);`

There are some.issue in using while(!feof(p)) !

Comment: He should be aware of that `feof()` inside `while` loop can create problem. Instead `fgets()` can be used.

Comment: Yes , i mentioned it in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

A. Use one `int temporary_array[BIG_ENOUGH];`

B. Use two integer variables, `int num;`, `int i=0;`, one integer pointer,  `int *a`.

C. Open the file

D. Read each character. For each character do the following:

1. If the ascii  code of the character is that of a number,  then do `num = whatEverThatNumberIs;`. Then do `temporary_array [i] =num;` `i++;`
2. When you get a `\n`, you've got one line. Do `a = malloc(i*sizeof (int));` Then copy each element from `temporary_array [ ]` to `a [ ]`. Then do `i=0;`.

   NOW YOU HAVE YOUR ARRAY `a [i]`. Do the operation you want to do in this array.
3. `free (a);`

Do this until you reach the end of file.  I guess this is one way you can do it.